# How to use xPath in Selenium WebDriver to grab SVG elements?

Tags: java, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I am testing an API, based on `OpenLayers`, with Selenium `WebDriver` (Java version).

I want to test a functionality that uses `OpenLayers`.Control.ModifyFeature. I want to click on drawn features (SVG), drag then and check if they are present, visible or hidden.

I have drawn a polygon, and I have selected it. See the image below:

[image: polygon_and_handles]

The HTML of these SVG elements is here:

```
<svg id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_161_svgRoot" width="1235" height="495" viewBox="0 0 1235 495" style="display: block;">
    <g id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_161_root" transform="" style="visibility: visible;">
        <g id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_161_vroot">
            <path id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Polygon_200" d=" M 393.0000000000964,213.9999999999891 486.0000000003338,275.9999999997126 384.00000000036925,284.9999999994434 393.0000000000964,213.9999999999891 z" fill-rule="evenodd" fill="blue" fill-opacity="0.4" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="pointer" />
            <circle id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_619" cx="439.50000000021464" cy="244.99999999985084" r="6" fill="#009900" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#ee9900" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="inherit" />
            <circle id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_621" cx="435.00000000035106" cy="280.49999999958163" r="6" fill="#009900" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#ee9900" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="inherit" />
            <circle id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_623" cx="388.50000000023283" cy="249.4999999997126" r="6" fill="#009900" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#ee9900" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="inherit" />
            <circle id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_202" cx="393.0000000000964" cy="213.9999999999891" r="6" fill="#990000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#ee9900" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="inherit" />
            <circle id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_203" cx="486.0000000003338" cy="275.9999999997126" r="6" fill="#990000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#ee9900" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="inherit" />
            <circle id="OpenLayers_Geometry_Point_204" cx="384.00000000036925" cy="284.9999999994434" r="6" fill="#990000" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#ee9900" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dasharray="none" pointer-events="visiblePainted" cursor="inherit" />
        </g>
        <g id="OpenLayers_Layer_Vector_161_troot" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Suppose I want to select the red points.

I tried:

```
String xpath = "//circle[contains(@id, 'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point') AND fill = '#990000']";
List<WebElement> vertices = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
```

But it always returns an empty list `[]`.

What am I doing wrong here? Could anybody help me, please?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT 1 - Function: verticesAreVisible**

Before the clicking actions, I want to get the elements and check if they are visible. I am using this function.

```
public static boolean verticesAreVisible(WebDriver driver, String xpath) {
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    boolean visible = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        visible = visible && list.get(i).isDisplayed();
    }
    return !verticesAreNotVisible(driver) && visible;
}
```

**EDIT 2 - Correct xPath**

```
// This solution from Razib is valid if the SVG is on the root node
String xpath = "/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='circle']";
// I changed it so that any descendant is valid "//"
String xpath = "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='circle']";
// Since I wanted only the red vertices, I added this
String xpath = "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='circle' and @fill='#990000']";
```

Comment: Hi I find this xpath is more easy to use, actions is not needed. //*[local-name()='svg']//*[local- name()='g' and and @fill='#990000'']

Answer (score 45, accepted):

May be you need to use the Actions with `name` attribute in `Xpath`. 
In your XPath use it -

```
"/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='SVG OBJECT']"
```

Then try the following code snippet -

```
WebElement svgObj = driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH));
Actions actionBuilder = new Actions(driver);
actionBuilder.click(svgObj).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 6):

To locate the red points i.e. the elements with attribute `fill="#990000"` and *id* attribute containing **OpenLayers_Geometry_Point** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

  ```
  //*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='circle' and contains(@fill, '990000')][starts-with(@id, 'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point')]
  ```
- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

  ```
  svg > g > g circle[fill$='990000'][id^='OpenLayers_Geometry_Point']
  ```

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies*:

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> vertices = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("svg > g > g circle[fill$='990000'][id^='OpenLayers_Geometry_Point']")));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> vertices = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='circle' and contains(@fill, '990000')][starts-with(@id, 'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point')]")));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant details discussions in:

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)
- [Creating XPATH for svg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024052/creating-xpath-for-svg-tag/49024531#49024531)
- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)

Answer (score 2):

Try `@fill` instead of `fill` and `OpenLayers_Geometry_Point` instead of `OpenLayers.Geometry.Point`.

Comment: Hi @peetya. Thanks for the 'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point' tip. I completely forgot to replace dots with underscores. Anyway, the '@fill' tip did not work. If I use this xPath '//*[contains(@id, 'OpenLayers_Geometry_Point')]', I get the 6 points. But I only want the 3 red.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the similar issue in one of the screens where we have SVG implementation, I resolved using action class.

```
Action Class Package :
java.lang.Object
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
```

Sample Code :

```
WebElement svgObject= driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH));
Actions actionBuilderObj = new Actions(driver);
actionBuilderObj .click(svgObject).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with all sort of techniques to dive Inn but atlast I found out an easy way to handle this situation.
When your desired svg doesnt have name and proper xpath changes dynamically then I used "cssSelector"

```
WebElement DesiredSvg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#scrollable-auto-tabpanel-0 > div > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.jss10127 > div > div.jss11602 > svg:nth-child(3)"));

DesiredSvg.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get just visibile elements you can use:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("bla bla")));
```