# How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, selenium-webdriver, amcharts

I have an `SVG` object with a few rectangle elements. Using `geckodriver`, I am trying to click on one of the main `SVG` object. However with xpath-checker I am unable to detect the proper `xpath` for the same.

Till now, I am able to drilldown through `xpath` upto:

```
id('avg_score_chart')/div/div[1]/*[local-name()='svg' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']
```

My `HTML` code is as follows:

```
<div id="avg_score_chart" class="chart" style="height: 250px; color: black ! important; overflow: hidden; text-align: left;">
<div class="amcharts-main-div" style="position: relative;">
<div class="amcharts-chart-div" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; text-align: left; width: 525px; height: 212px; padding: 0px;">
<svg version="1.1" style="position: absolute; width: 525px; height: 212px; top: 0.450012px; left: -0.5px;">
<desc>JavaScript chart by amCharts 3.17.1</desc>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g transform="translate(60,52)">
<g transform="translate(96,41)">
<g transform="translate(96,123)">
<g transform="translate(96,123)">
<path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,0.5 L0.5,-81.5 L30.5,-81.5 L30.5,0.5 L0.5,0.5 Z" fill="rgb(242,244,28)" stroke="rgb(242,244,28)" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.8">
</g>
<g transform="translate(318,123)">
<g transform="translate(318,123)">
<g transform="translate(318,123)">
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
<g>
</svg>
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following `XPath` and let me know if problem still persist:

```
//div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//*[name()="svg"]
```

For `<g>` elements:

```
//div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]
```

**Update**

Finally, this should be nearly the best option:

```
//div[@class="portlet light boxshadow"][contains(.,"Store Wise Performance")]/div//div[@class="amcharts-chart-div"]/*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"]/*[name()="path" and @fill="rgb(242,244,28)"]
```

Comment: That's weird... I would have expected the SVG tag to work like any other tag, e.g. `//div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//svg`. Do you know why you have to use `name()`?

Comment: For some tags (mostly from `XML` `DOM`)  one need to use `/*[name()=tag_name]` syntax instead of common `/tag_name`... Sorry, have no idea why it so

Comment: @Dev, please mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: @Andersson, Thanks a ton for your valuable suggestion.
1. Using xpath as:
  /div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//*[name()="svg"]
I can see (through xPathChecker) the Average Score Chart which have 2 elements and I want to click the first element.

2. Using xpath as:
 //div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]
The XPathChecker finds 18 elements, which is the total number of SVG elements on the page.

But I am still clueless how to get the xPath of the element for which I have pasted the code above.

Comment: @Dev, If there a few `svg` elements on page you can choose index to select second element: `(//div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//*[name()="svg"])[2]`. Tell me what is your target element as it's not quite clear from your question

Comment: Tried with this xPath:
 //div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path'][starts-with(@d, 'M371.75,174.28l')]
But it fails to detect & Click(As I am using Eclipse, I converted the double-quotes to single-quotes). So my click event was:
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path'][starts-with(@d, 'M371.75,174.28l')]")).click();

Comment: As per my pasted code, my target was: Within SVG, the g[5] element (i.e. starting from 0), within that g[0] element, within that g[2] element

Comment: You mean that one `<g transform="translate(96,123)">
            <path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,0.5 L0.5,-81.5 L30.5,-81.5 L30.5,0.5 L0.5,0.5 Z" fill="rgb(242,244,28)" stroke="rgb(242,244,28)" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.8">
          </g>` ?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for that and even //div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][5]/*[name()='g'][2] is not fetching me results through xChecker

Comment: And how about this one `(//div[@id="avg_score_chart"]//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"])[10]`?

Comment: @Andersson, thanks for your kind help. But this xPath //div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'‌​])[10] showed error through xPathChecker & when executed through Eclipse gecko thrown an exception. Can you please guide me further ?

Answer (score 2):

how about:
`//div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[local-name()='svg']/*[*[local-name()='path']]`

where you find any element with a 'path' element inside an 'svg' element inside a 'div' element with id 'avg_score_chart'.

Edit: placed the xpath in a code block

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. I have tried out both the options but xPathChecker fails to detect element & Eclipse throws exception:

//div[@id='avg_score_chart']//[local-name()='svg']/[*[local-name()='path']] and
//div[@id='avg_score_chart']//[local-name()='svg']/[*[local-name()='path'][starts-with(@d, 'M371.75,174.28l')]]

Can you please guide me further?

Comment: wait some of the characters are missing... got escaped probably. here's the correct one: `//div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[local-name()='svg']/*[*[local-name()='path']]`

Comment: take note of the asterisk before local-name()='svg' and the two asterisks before local-name()='path'

Comment: Thanks a lot. I too have tried with    //div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[local-name()='svg']/*[*[loca‌​l-name()='path']] but xPathChecker returned error & Eclipse thrown an exception. I have updated the complete DOM. Would you please have a relook at that?

Comment: how about `//div[@id='avg_score_chart']//*[local-name()='svg']//*[*[loca‌​l-name()='path']]`