# Selenium - Kendo UI Line Graph

Tags: selenium, kendo-ui

I'm working on a Test Automation framework using Selenium and most of the testing is done on Kendo UI pages. One of the problems I'm having is the graph testing, there are two types of graphs on the page, bar chart and line graph. I have no trouble testing the bar chart, I simply get the < g > and < path > elements and find the one I need etc. But it's different with the line chart. Both < g > and < path > elements are generated when I hover over the graph, when the page loads the paths are simply not created. There's only a single  object with all of the positions eg.

```
M57.295 40.425 L 59.885 40.425 62.475 40.425 65.066 40.425
```

... and a bunch of numbers after this. Unfortunately I cannot provide the URL to the website. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver \[Java\]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)

Comment: As explained above, my problem is not with finding the g and path elements (already figured that out with the bar chart), my problem is that they are not being generated on page load. They're only generated when I hover my mouse over a point on the along the line.

Comment: Can you share your code trials, the relevant HTML & the Selenium Client you're using?