# Scraping hover over figure using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, hover

I am trying to scrape the data from http://fuelinsights.gasbuddy.com/Charts using Python and Selenium.  The difficult part is that the data only appear when a point on the line graph is hovered over.  Currently, my issue is an inability to create a list of all the hover over objects.  My code so far is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver as web
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = web.Chrome('driver path')

driver.get('http://fuelinsights.gasbuddy.com/Charts')

test= driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="highcharts-markers"]')

print(test)
```

`

which gives me test=[].  Previously, I have used beautifulsoup for all of my scraping projects, but I have redone some of my previous projects to make sure that I understand how Selenium works and haven't had issues.

If anyone can help me solve this issue so I can create a list of the items that I can use ActionChains to hover over and extract the price and date from it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

****EDIT****
To clarify, I have looked over numerous other posts concerning SVG and g elements and Highcharts, but I am still short on a solution to this problem.  I have tried numerous Xpaths (and other find_elements_by options), but have only been able to come to two results: (1) the Xpath is valid, but does not contain any elements, or (2) InvalidSelectorException indicating that I was unable to locate an element with the xpath expression.  I believe this comes down to simply incorrectly specifying my Xpath, but I am at a loss for how to find the correct Xpath.

Comment: The `highcharts-markers` class is within a `<g>` tag which is within a `svg` tag. Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver \[Java\]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB this has provided some useful insight.  These are very similar questions, but I have been unable to solve my problem using the proposed solutions provided in the link (admittedly this could be due to my own shortcomings converting from Java to Python though).

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the Xpath which you have mentioned above for locating the elements inside the svg tag.

**Xpath which you can use to create a list of hover objects is:**

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-markers']/*[name()='path']
```

I have written a **java program** for getting the text of all the tool-tip elements. You can use the logic and write a corresponding python code:

**1.** **Get List of tooltip Elements**

```
 List <WebElement> highChartElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-markers']/*[name()='path']"));
```

**2. Iterate through the list and use action class for moving and clicking on all the tooltip Elements**

**3. Get the text of the tooltip elements.**

```
for(WebElement element:highChartElements){
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        List<WebElement> highChartToolTipTextElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-tooltip']/*[name()='text']/*[name()='tspan']"));
        for(WebElement toolTipElement:highChartToolTipTextElements){
            System.out.println("The text for the elements is"+toolTipElement.getText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Monika, thanks for the pointers.  I had to tweak the Xpath you provided slightly for it to run, but I still am getting an empty list back from the driver.find_elements_by_xpath command.  My Xpath is now 
             '//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"]//*[@class="highcharts-markers"]/*[name="path"]'

do you have any other advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't change the xpath, use the one I have provided. The xpath should work, I have executed the program on my machine and it worked.Why did you tweak the Xpath?

Comment: The Xpath you specified when used in python in the following command `test= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-markers']/*[name()='path']")` returns test=[].  I'm not sure why this provides you with results, but returns nothing to me.  Any further guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks You ! 2 years later, i'm facing to an equivalent project and used your example to learn how to get the job done with python & Firefox.
Perhaps the following code will be useful to some people.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'path\to\the\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://fuelinsights.gasbuddy.com/Charts')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "highcharts-markers")))
test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='highcharts-markers']/*[name()='path']")

res = []
for el in test:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el)
    hover.perform()
    date = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".highcharts-tooltip > text:nth-child(5) > tspan:nth-child(1)")
    price = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".highcharts-tooltip > text:nth-child(5) > tspan:nth-child(4)")
    res.append((date[0].text, price[0].text))
```

"res" contains :

```
('Saturday, May 30, 2020', '1.978 $/gal')
('Friday, May 29, 2020', '1.979 $/gal')
('Thursday, May 28, 2020', '1.977 $/gal')
('Wednesday, May 27, 2020', '1.972 $/gal')
('Tuesday, May 26, 2020', '1.965 $/gal')
.......
```

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue but on a different website. This solution didn't help me