# Finding Element's xpath address

Tags: java, selenium, web-testing, katalon-recorder

I'm trying to get an attribute of the small arrow next to 'Date' that is shown in the pic:

[image: Element's Xpath]

I used Katalon recorder to find the element's xpath address, and it gave me the following xpath:

```
"//div[5]/sort-direction/iron-icon[2]"
```

But this xpath is not enough, because I need the "d" attribute which is inside the 'path' tag (as you can see in the pic).

I tried to modify the xpath like this :

```
"//div[5]/sort-direction/iron-icon[2]/svg/g/path"
```

But then I got an `NoSuchElementException` exception.

Any ideas of how to get this attribute?

Comment: Are there any other `svg` or `g` elements inside `iron-icon[2]`?

Comment: Xpath looks fine from 'sort-direction', Verify the div[5] once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver \[Java\]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)

Comment: @DebanjanB [SOLVED] Thank you very much!!....Apparently there are several tags that you need to use /*[name()='tag_name'] syntax and svg/g/path are included in those tags so the right xpath is: 
"//div[5]/sort-direction/iron-icon[2]/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='path']

Comment: @DebanjanB Don't have enough reps I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the count of iron-icon. From picture given, it seems the "d" attribute you are trying to fetch is under the hierarchy of iron-icon at index 1 not 2.

Please try the `xpath` as :

```
"//div[5]/sort-direction/iron-icon[1]/svg/g/path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `svg`, and change `iron-icon[2]` to `iron-icon[1]`, which *is* `svg`. You don't need them both.