# keep reload the page after 2 minutes in selenium with php

Tags: php, selenium

I am newbie to selenium.I want to reload the same url page after 2 minutes.
i have tried following code but its not working:-

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
        $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html /body/div[1]/div/div[4]/button/svg/path[1]'))->click();
       // $this->webDriver->quit();
       // echo $this->webDriver->getTitle() . "\n";
        //$this->webDriver->navigate()->back();
    }
```

Comment: You can use sleep function inside your loop setSpeed(1000)

Comment: i want to load the same url again and again after 2 min. i have tried setspeed but my page didnot load again.

Answer (score 1):

As per the code block you have shared the loop won't get completed as following line will throw an exception :

```
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html /body/div[1]/div/div[4]/button/svg/path[1]'))->click();
```

That is because, *webDriver* wouldn't be able to locate the *webelement* through the *Locator Strategy* you have adopted and possibly throw `NoSuchElement` as `<svg>` elements are from a different [**svg**](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) namespace.

### Solution

You have to take help of a *Locator Strategy* to construct a proper *Locator* to identify and detect the `<svg>` element and then try to invoke `click()` method on it.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [*Selenium WebDriver [Java]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)

Comment: i have removed this line $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html /body/div[1]/div/div[4]/button/svg/path[1]'))->click(); but still selenim didnot open the url again n again

Comment: `didnot open the url again` doesn't throw any light on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current code trial and error stack trace.