# I want to write XPath for below HTML code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is an HTML code I need help to write XPath for this. I have tried to write x-path but it does not hit the system correctly?

```
<div class="col-1-12" data-reactid="17">
    <button class="vh79eN" type="submit" data-reactid="18">
    <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 17 18" class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-reactid="19">
    <g fill="#2874F1" fill-rule="evenodd" data-reactid="20">
    <path class="_2BhAHa" d="m11.618 9.897l4.225 4.212c.092.092.101.232.02.313l-1.465 1.46c-.081.081-.221.072-.314-.02l-4.216-4.203" data-reactid="21">
    </path>
    <path class="_2BhAHa" d="m6.486 10.901c-2.42 0-4.381-1.956-4.381-4.368 0-2.413 1.961-4.369 4.381-4.369 2.42 0 4.381 1.956 4.381 4.369 0 2.413-1.961 4.368-4.381 4.368m0-10.835c-3.582 0-6.486 2.895-6.486 6.467 0 3.572 2.904 6.467 6.486 6.467 3.582 0 6.486-2.895 6.486-6.467 0-3.572-2.904-6.467-6.486-6.467" data-reactid="22">
    </path>
    </g>
    </svg>
    </button>
    </div>
```

Please, help me to write correct XPath I have tried with:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-1-12']//button[@class='vh79eN']")).click();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: <div class="col-1-12" data-reactid="17"><button class="vh79eN" type="submit" data-reactid="18"><svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 17 18" class="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-reactid="19">

Comment: getting any error or what ?

Comment: Drop one of the slashes in the middle - `//div[@class='col-1-12']/button[@class='vh79eN']`

Comment: Try to use `@type` instead of `@class`: `//div[@class='col-1-12']/button[@type='submit']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver \[Java\]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)

Comment: @Andersson I tried but getting below issue:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@Type='col-1-12']/button[@type='submit']"}
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)

Comment: @suyash_sunny , try to use [ExplicitWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem : I tried you solution also but below error: 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@Type='col-1-12']/button[@class='vh79eN']"}
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.186)

Comment: @NarendraR :yes I got error written in the comment above

Comment: If that's the error you got, then you did _not_ try my solution.

Comment: @suyash_sunny, the xpath you are giving is written by you manually or it is generated by inspecting element?

Comment: @suyash_sunny, did you try my answer?

Comment: @RabiaAsif: I am trying to create by myself.

Comment: @suyash_sunny Ok then I would recommend you to inspect the element on browser and get the xpath which is already driven. If you have no idea about inspecting and getting xpath this way do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath can be tried :

```
//div/button[@class='vh79eN'][@type='submit']
```

So the function will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button[@class='vh79eN'][@type='submit']")).click().
```

Answer (score 0):

If data-reactid is consistent every time page is visited, you could try: `//button[@data-reactid='18']`

Note: If the element is inside of an iframe, you will have to switch to the iframe, then try to click.