# Getting value from tooltip when hover on svg element on the graph created with highcharts

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, graph, highcharts

I want to get text/value from the `tooltip` which appears when hover on svg element on the graph created with highcharts.
Below is the snippet:

[image: Highchart graph snippet]

Tried below code:

```
List<WebElement> Volumelist=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'][5]//*[name()='g'][2]//*[name()='path']"));
System.out.println("Got the list!");        
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(Volumelist.get(1)).clickAndHold().build().perform();
WebElement toolTip=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='highcharts-halo highcharts-color-3'][@visibility='visible']")));  
System.out.println("toolTip text= "+toolTip.getText());
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML Source code after hovering over point you want to extract the information from. Usually, the tooltip is contained in a separate div lower in the HTML source.

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath

Comment: @DebanjanB I think OP is having issues with locating the tooltip in the HTML source code and not with hovering on the point itself

Comment: If you just want the actual values from the graph, you can just use a point event in highchart, see: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/ Or even simpler: putting the values in console: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/tzugyx7L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hover on the element on which tooltip appears and then execute :

```
String tooltipText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("g.highcharts-tooltip text tspan")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

You can ping me at sandpdangi13@gmail.com if that does not work for you.

Try to hover to tooltip element using this method if normal Actions hover is not working :

```
 public static void mouseHoverJScript(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
        String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false);"
                + " arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,
                element);
```

Comment: Tried this also but for Tooltip.getAttribute("textContent") it says element not found. I think hover is not working properly as I am able to locate tooltip & element on which tooltip appears with firepath.

Comment: Thanks All for responses. I resolved hover issue with below code: new Actions(driver).moveToElement(elem).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(1, 1).pause(1000).perform();

Answer (score 0):

I found over their [examples page](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) the values with this XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*[name()="g" and contains(@class,"highcharts-label")]//*[name()="tspan" and @style='font-weight:bold'])).getText();
```

The first step is move the mouse over one point, for example with this XPath, move to the first point:

```
WebElement elem = DriverUtils.driver.findElement(By.xpath(.//*[name()='path' and contains(@class, 'highcharts-point highcharts-color')][1]));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(elem).clickAndHold().build().perform();
```

I used the Selenium 3.9.0, with previous 3.4.0 version doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ sagarwadhwa1 Yes,I have issue with locatiing tooltip. I guess this is tooltip element from HTML source : <path fill-opacity="0.25" class="highcharts-halo highcharts-color-3" d="M 77 22.099999999999994 A 0 0 0 1 1 77 22.099999999999994 Z" visibility="visible" fill="#f7a35c"></path> visibility of this tag becomes 'hidden' when mouse is out & 'visible' when hover on point on graph.

Comment: I add my Java code and the detail for Selenium version, I think it is so relevant.

Answer (score 0):

So, solution that worked for me:

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'][5]//*[name()='g'][2]//*[name()='path'][1]"));
        new Actions(driver).moveToElement(elem).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(1, 1).pause(1000).perform();
        String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'][9]//*[name()='text'][1]//*[name()='tspan'][3]")).getText();