# Scraping using Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[image: Numbers are in chart]
I am trying to get numbers such as 14,401. I tried something like

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='wiz-iframe-intent']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="highcharts-5tawcvw-0"]/svg/g[8]/g[1]/text/tspan[1]'))).text
```

getting TimeOut Exception.

Comment: Can you share the HTML in text format.

Comment: ```<tspan x="0" y="11" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" style="">14,401 (100%)</tspan> ```

Comment: Are you sure that you are in iframe ?

Comment: yes I am sure of it

Comment: @AbhishekGupta The elements you are trying to interact with are from the **svg** _namespace_. This discussion [Selenium WebDriver Java: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath) may help you.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta : Can you tell me the navigation steps ? I have created one account and I am on dashboard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular element is in **SVG.** you can follow this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://eu1.dashboard.clevertap.com/login.html")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"wiz-iframe-intent")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='CT_Interstitial']//span[@class='CT_InterstitialClose']"))).click()

driver.switch_to.default_content()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys("username")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"password"))).send_keys("****")  

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"submitBtn"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ct-breadcrumb')))

try:
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"wiz-iframe-intent")))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.close-btn.js-close-popup>button"))).click()
except:
    pass

driver.switch_to.default_content()  
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.sidebar__brand+ul>li:first-child>a")).perform()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "All Boards")))  

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"All Boards"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"pe-funnel"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='tspan' and contains(@stroke-linejoin,'round')]"))) 

all_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[name()='tspan' and contains(@stroke-linejoin,'round')]")

print(len(all_data))

for data in all_data:
 print(data.text)
```

Comment: due to new functionalities of clevertap the last two lines are giving error.

Comment: Can you raise a new ticket for the same ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332877/svg-tag-scraping-from-funnels