# Select element of a graph with selenium Xpath when mouseover

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium Xpath to get data from Semrush.

At this time, I want to select a label that is only showed when mouse is over of this bar graph.
The point is that the labels of the graph are just up when the mouse is over of each bar.

I want each of the values of the bar graph.
I used selenium KDE to select the link but it didn't worked:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='highcharts-26']/div/span/a") #grab that stuff you wanted?  

lista=[]

for e in elements:
    lista.append(e.get_attribute('class').strip()) #print text fields

dados[i]=lista
str1 = ''.join(lista)
websites.loc[websites['URL']==i,'1 a 3']=str1
print('keywords 1 a 3' + str1)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to _Mouse Hover_ over the element and possibly you have to handle the elements from **svg** namespace. Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath