# How to write locator for a below tag element for WebDriver using Java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

That is the HTML piece of the element which i need to click, I am getting "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException"

```
<svg viewBox="0 12.705 512 486.59" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" style="margin-right: 
0px;">

<svg viewBox="0 12.705 512 486.59" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" style="margin- 
right: 0px;">
<defs>
<polygon points="256.814,12.705 317.205,198.566 512.631,198.566 
354.529,313.435 414.918,499.295 256.814,384.427 98.713,499.295 
159.102,313.435 1,198.566 196.426,198.566 " style="fill: 
url(#jRate_grad4);stroke:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:2px;">
</svg>
```

I used below code:

```
>WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='jRate']/svg[5]/"));
>JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
>js.executeScript("argument[0].click()", ele);
```

I tried to find the element and just click on it, because of exception, I used JavaScript and issue is same. I don't know what I am missing here.

Java related help is much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the closing `/` from the `xpath`.

Comment: still not working!

Comment: Remove dot from xpath and last closing / - use this - //*[@id='jRate']/svg[5]

Comment: @Dhru'soni ok, that changed the exception "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException" is now on screen.

Comment: @Dhru'soni I was able to figure it out after 2 hours of work,, i used simple custom XPATH and it worked like chat.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@Style='fill: url(#jRate_grad4);stroke:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:2px;']")); is the answer for the question.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPulivarthi Instead of being offensive and criticize *"moderators"* look at your question once more and ask yourself "Is my question good? Did I share enough information to receive good answer?". I think the answer will be "No". [This ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath) contain solution for handling svg-nodes. Also your solution (from comment) doesn't match your question

Comment: @Andersson If you could have properly read my question before editing, my question was just to locate a particular element, the item just belongs to a SVG tag, and thats not the main concern. If you think I am wrong and criticizing for nothing, then you shouldn't have deleted my comments, people here should have known who is wrong.

Comment: @Andersson anyway, if you could look at the question which made my question duplicate, it was left with out a proper answer, making duplicate would not get much attention from the people who want to answer. Being a moderator, you should go extra mile for the convenience of the users, not by deleting fact comments. Anyways, its your forum and your wish.. all I care about is the help I can get from some good people.

Comment: @Andersson I am very new to this community and I am learning what I am actually asking here. If i dont provide what you need to answer, ask me, I will provide the info you need, you simply cant mark a question just because both the question have "SVG" tag, thats just naive.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPulivarthi , I'm not a *moderator* and this is not *my forum*. I'm the *Selenium golden-badge user* and that means that I have enough competence to decide whether question already has answer among other SO tickets or not. Regarding your question: 1) *you asked for locator*, 2) *you shared source code for `svg` node*, 3) *your attempt `/svg[5]` in your code attempt means that you don't know how to handle elements from [SVG-namespace](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg)*... If you don't agree, that your question closed as duplicate, share enough arguments. For now it's obvious duplicate

Comment: @SaiKrishnaPulivarthi , note that provided solution should NOT be suitable to your case at 100%, but to give you the point of how to solve your issue

Comment: @Andersson i am not here for arguments, being a "Golden" badge holder, you should be kind enough to help a newbie, I created this question because the previous one didn't help. I cannot even make a comment on that question just to grab attention of the people who can solve my issue? What I should do then? Stop using SO? And just FYI, I handled the case as just as regular tags, hence the question cannot be duplicate with the SVG tag question, My question is just to find locator for the followed piece of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is invalid.  Remove the trailing slash

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove it when changing Xpath, actually even after removing it, the error is same. "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"

Comment: That is a different error message.  It indicates that it cannot find any element with that xpath.  Without seeing the HTML it is hard to help further

Comment: <svg viewBox="0 12.705 512 486.59" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="20" width="20" style="margin-right: 0px;">
<defs>
<polygon points="256.814,12.705 317.205,198.566 512.631,198.566 354.529,313.435 414.918,499.295 256.814,384.427 98.713,499.295 159.102,313.435 1,198.566 196.426,198.566 " style="fill: url(#jRate_grad4);stroke:black;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:2px;">
</svg>

Comment: Robbie, please check the above HTML code, it wont allow me to add to body of question, hence here.

Comment: That is the html of the element you are expecting to return, no?  Can you provide the HTML that the search will be executed within?

Comment: yes, thats the HTML of the element i want  to return by my webdriver.