# Extract contents after click() with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, svg, modal-dialog, webdriverwait

I would like to extract the bio of a guy Herbert W. Gullquist. It is from "Manager Timeline" after clicking on his name ("Gullquist is chief investment officer and a general partner with Lazard Asset Management...") from this web page: https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/lziex/people

The code couldn't find the guy. Was it because the code clicked on the wrong place?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/lziex/people")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sal-component-ctn sal-component-manager-timeline-chart']//text[text()='Gullquist']/.."))).click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sal-modal-biography.ng-binding.ng-scope"))).text.strip())
```

In addition, what if I want everyone's bio (9 people in total) from the Manager Timeline instead of a certain person? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong `xpath` value at the line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sal-component-ctn sal-component-manager-timeline-chart']//text[text()='Gullquist']/.."))).click()
```

Change with the below value:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Herbert W. Gullquist']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 current managers and 3 past managers. To get both links

`current= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='current-manager-timeline']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']")
past = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='past-manager-timeline']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']")
total_links = current+past`

After getting the links, you can cycle over the links and extract the bio with

`bio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'biography')]").text`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am able to use the first block of code to get the links. How can I cycle over the links?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the bio of "Herbert W. Gullquist" from the web page https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/lziex/people and close the popup, as the element is within a `<tag>` tag, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/lziex/people")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sal-component-ctn sal-component-manager-timeline-chart']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='past-manager-timeline']//*[text()='Herbert W. Gullquist']"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.sal-modal-biography.ng-binding.ng-scope"))).text.strip())
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sal-component-ctn sal-modal-scrollable']//div[@class='sal-manager-modal__modalHeader']//button[@class='sal-icons sal-icons--close mds-button mds-button--icon-only']"))).click()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Gullquist is chief investment officer and a general partner with Lazard Asset Management, his employer since 1982. Previously, he spent 12 years as general partner, managing director, and chief investment officer of Oppenheimer & Company. Prior to that, from 1970 to 1971, he served as the director of Stuyvesant Asset Management, a company he founded. He has also worked at First National Bank of Chicago.
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please also help me close the popup window after extracting the bio? I tried WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg.mds-icon.mds-button__icon.mds-button__icon--left"))).click() but it didn't click the close button

Comment: @AlanZ Added the line of code to  close the popup window after extracting the bio. Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.