# How to click on svg element in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I have a problem with clicking on svg element in selenium Java.

HTML code:
[image]

I have tried next code examples but they are not helped.

```java
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
action.click(webElement).build().perform();
```

```java
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click;", webElement);
```

```java
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
Thread.sleep(2000);
action.moveToElement(webElement).click().build().perform();
```

I did not get any exception or error. But can not click on SVG element
Which solutions are exist for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) element so to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

> [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) compatible code

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[placement='bottom'] svg"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@placement='bottom']//*[name()='svg']"))).click();
  ```

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41829000/7429447)