# Get Text from SVG selenium java

Tags: java, html, selenium, testing, svg

I am uable to getText from Text tag in SVG. I am Attaching HTML

```
<svg width="553" height="200" style="overflow: hidden;" aria-label="A chart.">
     <defs id="defs">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="553" height="200" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">
     <g>
         <text text-anchor="start" x="77" y="22.85" font-family="Arial" font-size="11" font-weight="bold" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Clustering done on Mar 30, 2017 11:13 AM</text>
         <rect x="77" y="13.5" width="400" height="11" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff">
     </g>
```

The get I want to get is `Clustering done on Mar 30, 2017 11:13 AM`

Comment: Please, post the code where you're trying to get text

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520642/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements

Comment: 'String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='divClusters']/div[1]/div[1]/div/svg/g[1]/text")).getText();'
System.out.print(text)

Comment: this is error message**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element** @japu-d-cret

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use xPath in Selenium WebDriver to grab SVG elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520642/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements)

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely work:
1- driver.findElement(By.xpath("WriteXpathHere")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));

OR

2- driver.findElement(By.xpath("WriteXpathHere")).getAttribute("textContent"));

Note: Even if there is no attribute by the name "innerHTML" or "TextContent" this will work. Just copy this and only insert the Xpath

For reference:
https://gist.github.com/sajithatharaka/37c33008e68f1649281790a103adc60c

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[local-name='svg']//*[local-name='g']//*[local-name='text']")).getText();
```

Answer (score -1):

This locator should work:

- `String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='divClusters']//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='A chart.']//*[name()='g']")).getText(‌​);
  System.out.print(text);`

Explanation:

- `.//div` - remove `.` to search the whole document, not just in currently selected context element
- remove absolute `/div[1]/..` divs reference since it's not reliable
- refer to svg element as `//*[name()='svg']`
- add some meaningful attribute `@aria-label='A chart.'` to svg element
- Elements inside svg should be handled in the same way: `//*[name()="g"], //*[name()="defs"]` - thanks to  **Andersson** for clarifying this.

Comment: No, you won't be able to find `svg` element in such way

Comment: Should we use `*[name()='svg']` instead of `//svg` ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly `//*[name()='svg']`

Comment: Elements inside `svg` should be handled in the same way: `//*[name()="g"]`, `//*[name()="defs"]`... fix `//g` also

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#divClusters svg > g‌ > text")).getText();
```