# Creating XPATH for svg tag

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html for SVG, pls help me with creating XPATH for same

```
<svg data-reactid=".1q.0.3.1.0" version="1.1" class="svg-connector">
   <circle data-reactid=".1q.0.3.1.0.0" r="7" cy="11" cx="11" class="inner-circle"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 20):

For `svg` nodes you need to use below syntax:

```
//*[name()="svg" and @class="svg-connector"]
```

This is because [common `HTML` nodes](https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/) and [`svg` nodes](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) belongs to different namespaces

Answer (score 10):

The `<svg>` elements are not from the [**XHTML**](https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/) namespace but belongs to [**SVG**](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) namespace. Hence you have to specify `name()="svg"` while constructing the `xpath` as follows :

```
//*[name()="svg" and @class="svg-connector"]//*[name()="circle" and @class="inner-circle"]
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [*Selenium WebDriver [Java]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)

Answer (score 1):

Other suggestions didn't work for me. Here is what did:

`//*[name() = 'svg'][contains(@class, 'input-class-name-here')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `xpath` :

```
//svg[@class='svg-connector']
```