# Selenium ElementClickInterceptedException: Other element would receive the click error clicking Like button on Instagram page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, instagram

I used to have the following python + selenium library code to like any IG post.

Below is a snippet code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

"""
imagine on chrome browser you click on any IG picture of a gallery
of a specific account
then you see only that specific picture have the heart icon to click to like
see printscreen below
"""
like = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[aria-label='Like']") 
like.get_attribute("aria-label")
like.click()  #error on this line !!!!!!
```

It used to work before, but recently I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span aria-label="Like" class="glyphsSpriteHeart__filled__16__white u-__7"></span> is not clickable at point (827, 76). Other element would receive the click: <div class=" _32yJO" role="dialog">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

[image: sample aria-like]

Comment: Try invoking click directly driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", like)

Answer (score 0):

The Element is in an `svg` tag. To interact with the `svg` tag, below is the syntax. [You can refer this.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements)

```
//*[local-name()='svg']
Or
//*[name()='svg']
```

As per the screenshot of the DOM, the xpath for the `Like` element would be:

```
//*[local-name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']
```

Do check if the xpath is unique locator for that element in the DOM (1/1 match). [You can refer this.](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, I think it will not work because I get 1/12 matches (not 1/1)

Comment: You can refer these links to get a 1/1 match locator - [LInk1](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/), [Link2](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *Instagram*  icon you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button svg[aria-label='Like']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button svg[aria-label='Like']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Creating XPATH for svg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024052/creating-xpath-for-svg-tag/49024531#49024531)
- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. I tired both XPATH AND CSS_METHOD but I get the following error :   -Call--
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

Typically the below xpath

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']
```

should represent all the link icon in HTMLDOM.

if you want to be more specific, i.e based on IG handle you would like to press like icon, then you should use this

```
//a[text()='barked']/ancestor::header/../../following-sibling::div[2]//descendant::span[2]//*[name()='svg']
```

Also, I would recommend you to have `ExplicitWait` driver `WebdriverWait`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "paste the above here"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer. I did what you said but i get "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"  In addition I checked the xpath as you mentionned but I get 1/12 matches (not 1/1)