# How to click on the X element to close the email subscription popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to close this email subscription popup by clicking on the X. I tried using xpath to select it but I've been unsuccessful.

Code trial:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[27]/div/div/div/div/div/div/button/svg/circle")).click();
```

Element snapshot:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element <kbd>X</kbd> within the email subscription popup is a [***SVG***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544849/7429447) element.

---

### Solution

To click on the [*svg*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024531/7429447) element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.marksdailyapple.com/#axzz3HChquQM8");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Close form 3'] > svg > path"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://hausrat.allianz.de/");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close form 3']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: marksdailyapple]

Answer (score 0):

In your case unique selector is `[role=dialog] button[aria-label*=Close]`

```java
WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.get("https://www.marksdailyapple.com/");
wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[role=dialog] button[aria-label*=Close]"))).click();
```