# How to get "dismiss-button" in google_vignette iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, vignette

How to get and click "dismiss-button" inside Google vignette?
I've already tried the standard solution from other posts but I get "NoSuchElementException"
The last digit in "aswift_" iframe is variable so I'm using a partial name match like this:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@name, 'aswift_')]")))

# doesn't work:
self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dismiss-button').click()

or:

# doesn't work:
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'dismiss-button')]".click()
```

To get that vignette you have to:

1. Enter https://www.automationexercise.com/
2. Click "Products"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMuM5.png)

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>X</kbd> within the google vignette popup is a [***SVG***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544849/7429447) element.

---

### Solution

To click on the [*svg*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024531/7429447) element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://www.automationexercise.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Products"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='aswift_4']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#dismiss-button[aria-label='Close ad'] svg path"))).click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get(url='https://www.automationexercise.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Products"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='aswift_4']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dismiss-button' and @aria-label='Close ad']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: automationexercise]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Can  you give me a hint what could be the reason that after clicking "Close" or "X" automatically by Selenium the google_vignette advertisement dissappears but the url remains like this: 'https://automationexercise.com/#google_vignette' ? It should change to 'https://automationexercise.com/products' like in your screenshot. Please note that if I close the vignette manualyy by my mouse I get correct url.