# Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart

Tags: selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath, kendo-ui, webdriverwait

I did try some of xpaths but seems no luck.

I want to click on country and then graph , Given below screenshot :

[image]

Website URL is : https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/column

I tried xpaths  :

```
//text(text()='India')


 //g//text(text()='India')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the desired elements are [SVG Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element) you need to consider the namespace and induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and to click on the **first** *bar* within the *graph* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/column")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='chart']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[text()='India']//following::*[name()='path']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='chart']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'][contains(@clip-path, 'url')]//*[name()='path']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: SVG_Click]

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can click India with the following Xpath `//*[text()='India']`

This is a really helpful [resource](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

I usually open chrome inspector and then hit cntrl+F to open up an interactive way to test my xpaths:

[image]

You can target the svgs by using their strokes, but note these may change often.   example: `//*[@d='M54.5 164.5 L 70.5 164.5 70.5 236.5 54.5 236.5Z' and @stroke='#03a9f4']`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works, Can you please help in xpath to click on graph after click on india?

Comment: yes, what on the graph do you want to click? @HelpingHands

Comment: on any one bar like here I marked where I want to click : http://prntscr.com/m8fek0

Comment: added more for you @HelpingHands hope this helps! best of luck

Answer (score 2):

The elements on chart are from [SVG-namespace](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg), so you cannot use common syntax to select those elements (you wouldn't be able to select element by its tag name, e.g. `//svg` or `//path`, etc)

You can try below to select `text` node with text `"India"`:

```
//*[name()="text" and text()="India"]
```