# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am a beginner in web scraping in selenium python. I am trying to scrape the data that shows the annual prices for the various drugs. However I am getting an error that says :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "other.py", line 11, in 
    paths = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid path")))
  File "wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

I am unsure what I have to do. The code I have so far is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'http://abacus.realendpoints.com/ConsoleTemplate.aspx?act=qlrd&req=nav&mop=abacus!main&pk=ed5a81ad-9367-41c8-aa6b-18a08199ddcf&ab-eff=1000&ab-tox=0.1&ab-nov=1&ab-rare=1&ab-pop=1&ab-dev=1&ab-prog=1.0&ab-need=1&ab-time=1543102810'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(d)
d.get(url)
paths = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid path")))
results = []
for path in paths:
    actions.move_to_element(path).perform()
    actions.click_and_hold(path).perform()
    items = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('#priceChart path + text tspan')
    result = [item.text for item in items]
    if result:
        results.append(result)
d.close()
print(results)
```

Comment: Please add the full Traceback error to your question.

Comment: What are the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: I am trying to extract the annual prices for each of the drugs at the top of the page. The price only appears when you hover over each of the separated rectangles

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441) discussion helps you?

Comment: No not really. I have no clue what my error is so

Answer (score 0):

If i search id as `"highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid"` in resources its saying 2 results found and if i search id `"highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid path"` its says me 0 match found i have share the screen shot please look into it and let us know

First Image using "highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid"
[image]

Second Image using "highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid path"

[image]

### UPDATE

Please visit this link if you want to learn how to find and use xpath :

https://confengine.com/selenium-conf-2018/proposal/6018/chropath-a-smarter-way-to-get-locators-and-verify-them

Comment: I guess it's the one without the path. However, I am unsure whether to use highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid or highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid

Comment: so can you just use another finder rather than css selector

Comment: Would I use XPath instead?

Comment: yes you can use xpath or id if available let us know if that works

Comment: I do not know how to use xpath or id. I looked at some online stuff but i'm not really able to understand how to code it