# How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, svg-rect

There is a rect object in the dom:

```
<rect class="slv-blank" id="id123" height="8.8" stroke-width="1px" width="18.8" x="59.2" y="37.5"></rect>
```

I am trying to search it with following code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//rect[@id="id123"]'))).click()
```

This does not work.

But the following does:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[name()="rect"][@id="id123"]'))).click()
```

Any clues on why the first one does not work?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*? what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `<rect>`

The [`<rect>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) element is a basic [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) shape that creates rectangles, defined by their corner's position, their width, and their height. The rectangles may have their corners rounded.

An Example:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 220 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Simple rect element -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />

  <!-- Rounded corner rect element -->
  <rect x="120" y="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" ry="15" />
</svg>
```

---

### Attributes

The [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect#Attributes) of `<rect>` elements are as follows:

- `x`: This attribute determines the x coordinate of the rect.

  - Value type: | ; Default value: 0; Animatable: yes
- `y`: This attribute determines the y coordinate of the rect.

  - Value type: | ; Default value: 0; Animatable: yes
- `width`: This attribute determines the width of the rect.

  - Value type: auto|| ; Default value: auto; Animatable: yes
- `height`: This attribute determines the height of the rect.

  - Value type: auto|| ; Default value: auto; Animatable: yes
- `rx`: This attribute determines the horizontal corner radius of the rect.

  - Value type: auto|| ; Default value: auto; Animatable: yes
- `ry`: This attribute determines the vertical corner radius of the rect.

  - Value type: auto|| ; Default value: auto; Animatable: yes
- `pathLength`: This attribute lets specify the total length for the path, in user units.

  - Value type:  ; Default value: none; Animatable: yes

> **Note**: Starting with SVG2 x, y, width, height, rx and ry are Geometry Properties, meaning those attributes can also be used as CSS properties for that element.

---

### This usecase

As the `<rect>` element is a **SVG** element so to locate such elements you have to explicitly specify the [SVG namespace](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) when accessing the elements using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

- For `<svg>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]
  ```
- For `<g>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]
  ```
- For `<rect>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect"]
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="rect"]
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)

Comment: Thanks - this is very well explained

Comment: You are deducing that there is a namespace involve and advising to *"explicitly specify the SVG namespace"*, but then your XPath expressions don't do that. Niether `//*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect"]` nor `//*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="rect"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Action` class or `JavaScript` Executor.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elememnt=WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[@id="id123"]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elememnt).click().perform()
```

OR

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elememnt=WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[@id="id123"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",elememnt)
```