# How to click a dropdown button within a svg tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I have a website where i want to download an excel file.
https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html

I want to be able to click the download button and then click download xls.
To click the first button i tried the following:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_by_element_located(By.XPATH('//path[@d="M 11.6 5 L 11.6 17 M 7.4 12.6 L 11.6 17 L 15.799999999999999 12.6 M 3 19 L 3 21 L 21 21 L 21 19"]'))).click()
```

and

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_by_element_located(By.XPATH('//path[@stroke-width="1.8"]'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//g[@aria-label="View export menu"]'))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH('//g[@aria-label="Chart export menu"]'))).click()
```

For the last two i get the " 'str' object is not callable" error, the first two options just don't work at all.

I can't seem to be able to click the button. I can't really find an 'id' or an unique class/name (the print button has the same class value) for the button, which would make this a lot easier.

I think i would also not be able to then click the "XLS downloaden" as I can't find an ID here either.

So, how would i go about clicking the first button, and then clicking the "XLS downloaden" ?

Comment: Which is that download button?

Comment: the small down arrow next to the print icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) element so to click on the element instead of `visibility_of_element_located()` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the **`element_to_be_clickable()`** and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.highcharts-container svg g[aria-label='View export menu'] rect"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.rivm.nl/media/smap/eenzaamheid.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='highcharts-container ']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @aria-label='View export menu']//*[name()='rect']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: svg_css_click]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [interacting with SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java) in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Comment: I already have all imports. I tried element to be clickable with By.XPATH('//g[@aria-label="Chart export menu"]'))).click(). But i still get the "not clickable" error. Are the name or id you provided the exact names and id's i could use?

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: That totally works! thanks! And how would i then go about then clicking "XLS Downloaden" ? In the same fashion?

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld Glad to be able to help you. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please? SO contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Will do! Just have to wait a bit since i can only post once every 90 minutes. and thanks again!

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld Sounds great !!! By the mean time feel free to browse through the linked discussions within my answer. I strongly believe you'd be able to do on your own ;) Good luck