# Scraping data from high charts

Tags: python, selenium, svg, highcharts, webdriverwait

I have two problems: first, I cannot click on the show all bottom; and, second, I cannot get the data from the high chart.

I saw some examples for the high chart on Stack Overflow; however, I did not get how people figure our which JS code to execute.

I tried the following code to achieve that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\XX\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
url = "https://siterankdata.com/wsj.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="smallchart"]/div/div/svg/g[17]/g/text/tspan').click() # Does not work I try to click on the show all button.
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Which is that element `//*[@id="smallchart"]/div/div/svg/g[17]/g/text/tspan` which you are trying to click?

Comment: To show all button

Comment: Hi @Dogukan Yılmaz, You can use JS global variable `Highcharts` to get acces to charts and execute for example: `Highcharts.charts[0].series[x].points` for data points.

Comment: Hi @Ppotaczek, I think the data is not loaded with a high chart but with AmCharts, do you have any idea about how to get that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know AmCharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on `show all` button Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`

```
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='smallchart']//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][17]/*[name()='g']/*[name()='text']/*[name()='tspan']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz : what data are you expecting from high chart?

Comment: The values from Website Ranking Data with dates and values

Answer (score 1):

The element with text as **Show all** is a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the **`element_to_be_clickable()`** and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://siterankdata.com/wsj.com")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#smallchart svg g text[text-anchor='start'] tspan"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://siterankdata.com/wsj.com")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id="smallchart"]//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and text()='Show all']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [interacting with SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java) in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Comment: Thank you and how about getting the data from the chart later?

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz Which data are you specifically looking at?

Comment: Date and ranking values from the same table that I click on the "Show All"

Comment: @DogukanYılmaz But those datas doesn't appears at a time. You have to  _Mouse Hover_ around using `ActionChains` and keep on scraping the data. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003).

Comment: Ok let me try to understand what was there and implement for my own

Comment: Well actually how to scrape data from the chart was a part of my question, so if I cannot figure that, I would still need help. I will accept once I get the data