# c# nosuchelementexception and chromedriver missing elements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I want to build a bot to bets roulette with c#,
I'm using selenium to find the numbers and click on them.
I'm having 2 problems, the first problem is when I inspect for numbers game screen not visible in the inspection screen [chromedriver inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3558.png), [normal chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzr0.png)
the second problem I tried firefox instead of chrome, all things looks fine but when I try find by XPath I'm getting this error

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element:
> /html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3558.png)/div/div[6]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3558.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3558.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzr0.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzr0.png)/div/svg/g/rect[20]'

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    IWebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
    IWebDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/svg/g/rect[20]")).Click();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://tulipbet328.com/");
    }
```

I just want to click on any number

Comment: you should target the id.  Your xpath will be much shorter.  "data-bet-spot-id" attribute.  (EX: //rect[@data-bet-spot-id='13']) It also looks like that may be inside an iframe (hard to tell from your screens...)  If so, you need to switch the driver to the <iframe> first: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(int)

Comment: thanks for your help, it was iframe

Answer (score 0):

As per the xpath - `/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/svg/g/rect[20]`, the element is in an **`svg`** tag.

Below is the syntax to interact with **`svg`** tag elements.

```
//*[local-name()='svg'] or //*[name()='svg']
```

The xpath should be something like this:

```
...//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='rect']
```

Instead of **Absolute xpath** go for **Relative xpaths**. And apply some waits, either Implicit or **Explixct**.

**Links to refer** - [Link1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/clicking-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath-selenium-webdriver), [Link2](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the *xpath* within the error message:

```
//html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div2/div/div[6]/div2/div/div2/div/div1/div/div1/div/svg/g/rect[20]
```

It's quite evident that the desired element is a *`<rect>`* element within it's parent *`<g>`* tag which is within it's parent *`<svg>`* tag.

---

### Solution

To click on the 20<sup>th</sup> element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("svg g rect:nth-child(20)")).Click();
  ```

  or

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("svg g rect:nth-of-type(20)")).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"]//*[name()="rect"][20]")).Click();
  ```

  or

  ```
  driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"]//*[name()="rect"]"))[20].Click();
  ```

---

### Update

To address *`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException`* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("element_css"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("element_xpath"))).Click();
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Reading title tag in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544775/reading-title-tag-in-svg/63544849#63544849)