# How to click on a rect tag in a bar graph using Selenium

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors, svg-rect

I have bar graph in a website and need to click on it. Using developer tools, I am getting below xpath:

```
/html/body/root/main/portal/div[2]/div/div/div/my-portal/div[3]/td-tyr/td-tyr/div[1]/filter-bar/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/bar-chart/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[4]/g[1]/rect[1]
```

When using the above in xpath, it's giving invalid expression. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the *Bar Graph* as the element have a parent `<svg>` element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bar-chart svg g rect.highcharts-point.highcharts-color-0.highcharts-point-hover[x='31.5'][y='40.5']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//bar-chart//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='rect'][@x='31.5' and @y='40.5']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on a ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "bar-chart svg g rect.highcharts-point.highcharts-color-0.highcharts-point-hover[x='31.5'][y='40.5']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//bar-chart//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='rect'][@x='31.5' and @y='40.5']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [interacting with SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java) in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//rect[@class='highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 highcharts-point-hover'][@stroke='#ffffff']
```

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//rect[@class='highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 highcharts-point-hover'][@stroke='#ffffff']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//rect[@class='highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 highcharts-point-hover'][@stroke='#ffffff']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//rect[@class='highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 highcharts-point-hover'][@stroke='#ffffff']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//rect[@class='highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 highcharts-point-hover'][@stroke='#ffffff']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: the classname is not unique. There are multiple bargraph in the website and classname is same for all , so the above code is unable to find an element

Comment: You should share more HTML content, outerHTML in that case. Else, you would end up using XPath indexing like this `(//rect[@class='highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 highcharts-point-hover'][@stroke='#ffffff'])[1]`... put `[2]` or `[3]` or any arbitrary number that matches the node you want to perform click action on. Steps are mention to check unique node above.