# Error in Clicking on SVG using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

Following is HTML code. I want to click on Export to CSV.

```
<pre>
<div id="leo-title-bar" style="width: 100%">
<div class="container-fluid p-0"><div class="no-gutters" style="min-height: 100vh;">
<div class="col-12 d-flex flex-column">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary justify-content-start" style="height: 64px; flex-wrap: unset;">
<span class="navbar-brand" style="flex: 1 1 0%; font-size: 22px;">Agency Summary</span>

<svg aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-5AhAR2Z9sKF8" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="download" class="svg-inline--fa fa-download fa-w-16 svg-shadow svg-icon-basic svg-icon-basic-hover" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">

<title id="svg-inline--fa-title-5AhAR2Z9sKF8">Export to CSV</title>

<path fill="currentColor" d="M216 0h80c13....."></path></svg>

</div></main>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</pre>
```

I have tried following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-12 d-flex flex-column"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-5AhAR2Z9sKF8"]').click()
```

Getting an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The desired element is a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) element. To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#leo-title-bar svg[data-icon='download']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='leo-title-bar']//*[name()='svg' and @data-icon='download']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [interacting with SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java) in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you are missing a delay.
So adding some dummy sleep like

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-12 d-flex flex-column"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-5AhAR2Z9sKF8"]').click()
```

Should resolve your problem.
Also your locator looks bad. You have to create more reliable locator.
Also you should use Expected Conditions explicit waits, as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
rom selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="col-12 d-flex flex-column"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-5AhAR2Z9sKF8"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding wait time  was one part of problem and creating a reliable element locator was other as you mentioned

Comment: As mentioned by undetected Selenium, in case we resolved your issue please accept (one of) the correct answer(s)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.../*[name()="svg"]...
```

to

```
.../*[local-name()="svg"]...
```

in your XPath-expression, because your `<svg...>` element is in the namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. Thing is that `name()` matches *namespace:name*, but `local-name()` only matches the name without the namespace(-prefix).