# How to find svg element with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

I'm building a python Instagram bot, and I'm trying to get it to click on the DMs icon, but I'm not sure how to select it.

I tried selecting by Xpath, but I can't seem to be able to navigate it to the icon.
Here's Instagram's html code for the DMs icon:

```
<svg aria-label="Messenger" class="_8-yf5 " color="#262626" fill="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to apply a slightly different locator strategy to find `svg`.

Here is what works:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']")
```

assuming that this is the only svg element (as provided in your query)

Combination of more than one attribute from the same DOM line:

```
//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Messenger']
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.
So, I've tried it, and it is in fact not the only svg tag in the html. It clicks on something else. Is there any way I could search it by the aria-label="Messenger"?

Comment: More DOM lines are to be investigated. Basically you have to traverse through a good unique locator down to this svg to have it work. Another way is to identify with multiple attributes, like `//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Messenger']`

Comment: Props to you man, it works. 
I really appreciate it. I'm relatively new to building bots and I don't know xpath expressions. Either way, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is a [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) element so to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[aria-label='Messenger']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Messenger']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [interacting with SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41829000/7429447) in:

- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57076157/7429447)
- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491696/7429447)

Comment: I really appreciate the help man!
Using just //*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Messenger']
worked.

Comment: @BikGer2 It isn't just the xpath but the [_`CSS_SELECTOR`_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) and [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) will be inevitable for you in the long run.

Comment: Alright, I'll take some time to read about it.

Thanks for the advice!