# How to locate an <image> tag within a webpage using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, svg, xpath

I want to locate the `image` tag in a webpage. The application contains a VIEW ICON. While inspecting the view icon, it is coded as `image` tag. I am not sure how to locate that particular tag.

Below is the image tag I want to locate:

```
<svg width="1em" height="1em" class="user-dropdown-icon" viewBox="0 0 14 8">
<image data-name="Vector Smart Object copy 3" width="14" height="8" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA4AAAAICAYAAADJEc7MAAAAx0lEQVQYlY2Pv2oCAQyHP//s9waZfIF7j+PG3nbDFQfB7ufaxV3c3BxcFaRduzj5GL/Z5Tr0j1AoKZGeoGggEJLvI0mnqqoDsDCzCXeEpCkw7AJroJb0fEsLpnanl6bpKzAAxk3TfCdJsrsiueDiCnjsmtkPUAIbYCrp6YLkPT/RmdIdP5WQC2ALzCSNWpLXs5gVwdI/AWZ2lOTyCzCX9B6jOfAGPDhz4v82tuRPIAP8z2Wk15mZfbXZMzHkDyAH9pF59P4D+AX710oK5f6gzQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></image>
</svg>
```

I tried with the below xpath:

```
xpath="(//*[@class='user-view-icon'])[11]")
```

But it did not work out

I want to locate the view icon

Comment: Can you please share the html code of your element?

Comment: No image tag supplied and no code showing us what you are trying to do.  Ideally link to the website in question, there just isn't enough information available to even begin to try and answer this.

Comment: <svg width="1em" class="user-edit-icon" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 14 14" xpath="1"><image width="14" height="14" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAA0UlEQVQokYXRsUpDQRCF4S8SBLUIgoWt2Fili0EQVKzsNKWFj2Ql6VPZWaZMBCuxVEPEJ7ARBNFGUEbuheVmkzvN7Bz258xhGnvXV2qqgVPEx3v0mnUEfnFTvM8wrIMusIYtvGAZJ0sLgCMM0McGdvCI9jynQ4yS+QHnAcSQczrAuKL94KMcqk4B3Fa0T3QwLYXUaT8DfKGbAil0jLsMsItJdf+AWnjFW6J/F8BzJvN/pku8Y7Po64uAEorw21gpcsVNnuYBJRS7x01Wc/vPFP4AspQkkhLJXfUAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></image></svg>

Comment: Above is the html code. I am trying to locate the image tag in it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Selenium - Java

```
/*get element by tag name*/
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.tagName("image"));
```

If there are more than one image on the page , use

```
/*get all elements by tag name*/
List<WebElement> images = driver.findElements(By.tagName("image"));
```

from the list above determine which one do you want to use(tip : use a foreach loop to iterate)

Comment: I tried the above one. I am getting Null Pointer Exception

Comment: I tried replicating your logic, and it worked for me . Have you checked if your driver object is null ? if the above code is throwing an error , it should be 'ElementNotFoundException'

Comment: I am getting the below error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at iss.objectRepository.ViewRolePage.clickView(ViewRolePage.java:26)
 at iss.stepDefinition.ViewRole.clickViewIconAndVerifyTheFields(ViewRole.java:27)
 at ?.When Click view icon and verify the fields(src/test/resources/ISSFeatures/ViewRole.feature:10)

Answer (score 1):

### `<image>`

The [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) SVG element includes images inside SVG documents. It can display [raster image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/raster_image) files or other SVG files.

The only image formats SVG software must support are [JPEG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/jpeg), [PNG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/PNG) and other SVG files. Animated [GIF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/gif) behavior is undefined.

SVG files displayed with `<image>` are [treated as an image:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image) external resources aren't loaded, [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) styles [aren't applied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector), and they cannot be interactive. To include dynamic SVG elements, try [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) with an external URL. To include SVG files and run scripts inside them, try [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) inside of [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

> **Note**: The HTML spec defines  as a synonym for  while parsing HTML. This specific element and its behavior only apply inside SVG documents or inline SVG.

---

### This usecase

As the `<image>` element is a **SVG** element so to locate such elements you have to explicitly specify the [SVG namespace](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) when accessing the elements using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

- For `<svg>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]
  ```
- For `<g>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]
  ```
- For `<image>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="image"]
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)

Answer (score 0):

You image doesn't have the "user-view-icon" CSS class assigned and XPath doesn't work.

you could do:

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg.user-dropdown-icon > image"));
```

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Can you please execute the code below and let me know what you get. System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName(“image”)).size());

if you still get null pointer exception , there is something wrong with your driver object . This code should return 0 if no image tag found on page , else the number of image tags on that page

Depending on the number of image tags , you can decide on the index of image tag you want to click , and then execute click on that element