# Clicking on svg using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, webdriver

svg icon is clickable.

```
<div class="some-class">
    <svg aria-label="Search" class="some-icon" width="24" height="24" fill="#000" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M9.5,...,5 9.5,5Z">
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchForm"]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[2]/svg/path').click()
```

Error:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="SearchForm"]/div[1]/span/div[1]/div[2]/svg/path"}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To `click()` on the svg icon you can use the following solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="some-class"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-label="Search"]').click()
```

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)

Answer (score 4):

The "svg" elements are not from the XHTML namespace but belongs to SVG namespace. Hence you have to specify name()="svg" while constructing the xpath for svg tags.
for example :
"/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path'] "

For your reference , please find below discussion
[How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)

Answer (score 0):

For my case the following worked:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="some-class"]/*[name()="svg"][@aria-label="Search"]').click()
```