# Search for an element inside another element [web crawling / python selenium]

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm crawling a card that not always have an SVG, but when it does I need to know that. I need to check whether an SVG exists inside a card. Here's what I have by now (that doesn't work):

```
jog = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='cartola-atletas__card cartola-atletas__card--com-parciais']")[k]
                    
if jog.find_element_by_xpath("./svg[@class='cartola-atleta-simples-capitao-label']").is_displayed():
     capitao = 'SIM'
```

This code never gets inside the if statement, even when its condition evaluates to true.

Here's the code I'm crawling:

```
<div class="cartola-atletas__card cartola-atletas__card--com-parciais">
     .
     .
     .
     <svg class="cartola-atleta-simples-capitao-label">
     .
     .
     .
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't get `svg` elements like that. see workaround using `name()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57076106/8375783