# InvalidSelectorException when trying to find elements by xlink:href attribute

Tags: .net, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to find elements like this:

```
<use xlink:href="site.org/path/action#edit"></use>
```

by a given attribute using this selector:

```
  public static By ElementsSelector { get; set; } = By.CssSelector(@"use[xlink:href='site.org/path/action#edit']");
```

and I find elements by:

```
 Driver.FindElements(EditProfilePage.ElementsSelector)[0].Click();
```

but I get an exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException: 'invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)'
```

**Question:** How can I find elements with a given `xlink:href` attribute?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB Done.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `@` in css selector:

```
public static By ElementsSelector { get; set; } = By.CssSelector("use[xlink:href='site.org/path/action#edit']");
```

Comment: Did you just remove `@` or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I removed it, I dont think it is required

Comment: @yoda, It should be `EditProfilePage.ElementsSelector` instead of `EditProfilePage.EditIconsSelector` right. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

### `<use>`

The [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else.

---

### xlink:href

The [`xlink:href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) attribute defines a reference to a resource as a reference [IRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Content_type#IRI). The exact meaning of that link depends on the context of each element using it.

An example:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 160 40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <a xlink:href="https://developer.mozilla.org/"><text x="10" y="25">MDN Web Docs</text></a>
</svg>
```

> **Note:** SVG 2 removed the need for the xlink namespace, so instead of xlink:href you should use href.

---

### This usecase

As the `<use>` element is a **SVG** element so to locate such elements you have to explicitly specify the [SVG namespace](https://www.w3.org/2000/svg) when accessing the elements using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) as follows:

- For `<svg>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]
  ```
- For `<g>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]
  ```
- For `<use>` elements:

  ```
  //*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="use"]
  ```

---

> **Additional Consideration**: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed
>   from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being
>   dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using
>   it, and update existing code if possible. Be aware that this feature
>   may cease to work at any time.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to access to 'rect' type element through Selenium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490461/how-to-access-to-rect-type-element-through-selenium-python/55491696#55491696)
- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)