# Get text from g tag within svg tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to get a text from a class tag using selenium and I kinda hit a dead end. All the classes name are the same "legend-row" but I only need the 3rd one, the one that has "1.09TB" text.

I have tried to find the element by xpath and no luck the only way that I managed to get the value from those classes was by using the below line of code

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("legend-row").text`

which gets me all the texts, 134.46Tb, 8.96TB, 1.09TB and Threshold Level 90%.
Is there any way that I can only query the 3rd one? See below the classes from the URL

```
<g class="legend" style="font-size: 14px;">
    <g class="legend-row" transform="translate(102,-32.400000000000006)">
        <rect y="-30.599999999999998" width="14" height="14" style="fill: rgb(125, 123, 140); stroke: rgb(125, 123, 140);"/>
        <text x="18" y="-18">Allocated:</text>
        <text x="109.421875" y="-18"> 134.46 TB</text>
    </g>
    <g class="legend-row" transform="translate(102,-10.800000000000004)">
        <rect y="-30.599999999999998" width="14" height="14" style="fill: rgb(110, 37, 133); stroke: rgb(110, 37, 133);"/>
        <text x="18" y="-18">Spare:</text>
        <text x="109.421875" y="-18"> 8.96 TB</text>
    </g>
    <g class="legend-row" transform="translate(102,10.799999999999997)">
        <rect y="-30.599999999999998" width="14" height="14" style="fill: rgb(130, 224, 170); stroke: rgb(130, 224, 170);"/>
        <text x="18" y="-18">Unallocated:</text>
        <text x="109.421875" y="-18"> 1.09 TB</text>
    </g>
    <g class="legend-th-row" transform="translate(102,32.39999999999999)">
        <text x="0" y="0" class="chart-status-icon" style="font-size: 14px; fill: rgb(242, 175, 0);"></text>
        <text x="18" y="0">Threshold Level: 90%</text>
    </g>
</g>
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Can you please point us to the URL so that we can investigate.

Comment: Hey @Pythonologist The url that I'm scrapping is not open to the public, it's an internal URL from a server in a local network. If I past here the source page would it help?

Comment: You are right about the index number [3] but for some reason the element can't be found. This is the xpath for the 3rd element "//*[@id="sc-storage-center-top-disk-folders_0"]/div/sc-storage-center-top-disk-folders/div/div[2]/dui-donut-chart/svg/g/g/g[3]" but if I try "driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="sc-storage-center-top-disk-folders_0"]/div/sc-storage-center-top-disk-folders/div/div[2]/dui-donut-chart/svg/g/g/g[3]""").text" i get the message "Message: Unable to locate element"

Comment: This is the message I'm getting from your suggested answer. "Message: Unable to locate element: (//g[@class='legend']/g[@class='legend-row'])[3]"

Comment: @PeterFranca As you mentioned `..//dui-donut-chart/svg/g/g/g[3]`, can you update the question with the text based html please?

Comment: Hey guys I managed to get the script working. I used all the mentioned options/answers here to come up with another idea which is working now. Thank you all for all the overwhelming help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code I have written by referring to your attached image -

```
mytxt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//g[@class='legend']/g[@class='legend-row'])[3]").text
Split_text = mytxt.split()

print(Split_text[1] + ' ' + Split_text[2])
```

Output = 1.09 TB

[image]

[image]

Note - Please play with the index number i.e. in our case [3].

Answer (score 1):

To print the *text* **1.09 TB** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//dui-donut-chart/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='g']//*[name()='g']//text[., 'Unallocated:']//following::text[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "dui-donut-chart>svg>g>g g:nth-of-type(3) text:nth-of-type(2)"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/how-to-click-on-svg-elements-using-xpath-and-selenium-webdriver-through-java)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Comment: Hey guys I managed to get the script working. I used all the mentioned options/answers here to come up with another idea which is working now. Thank you all for all the overwhelming help.

Answer (score 0):

Peter, If you're getting all of three values as text/string, then the easiest way to do that will be

```
string = "134.46Tb, 8.96TB, 1.09TB"
third_item = string.split(',')[2]
```

In the third_item variable, you'll have 1.09TB

Another way you can directly use **split()** after your function like this -

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("legend-row").text.split(',')[2]
```

**split()** will convert the text into a list of strings separated  with comma. You we can get a particular item using slicing.

Comment: Hey @Indrajeet Singh
Thanks for the suggestion. Using this line `UNALLOCATED_SPACE = driver.find_element_by_class_name("legend").text.split(',')[2]` I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.
To use the split function Do I need to import it first?

Comment: Try using this.
unallocatedSpace = driver.find_element_by_class_name("legend").text.split()[2]

Comment: I got it working with this line here `UNALLOCATED_SPACE = driver.find_element_by_class_name("legend").text.split()[5]` Result is `1.09`. I'm wondering why the TB was left off? This is kinda important for me query any guess?

Comment: can you paste the exact text you're getting in UNALLOCATED_SPACE ? , so we can see it. Because i am am also getting TB from the string you mentioned in the question

Comment: Hey guys I managed to get the script working. I used all the mentioned options/answers here to come up with another idea which is working now. Thank you all for all the overwhelming help.

Comment: Amazing Peter, don't forget to accept and answer and upvote.