# Reading title tag in svg?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath, css-selectors

How do I read the text in  below? svg seems to be a special case.

Tried the below, but of no help

//*[name()='svg']/title

//*[name()='svg' and @title='Test']

//*[name()='svg' and contains(@title,'Test')]

> ```
>     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 137 125" version="1.1">
>         <title>Test</title>
>         <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the text from the `<title>` tag within the [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  svg>title
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `name()`:

  ```
  //*[name()='svg']/*[name()='title']
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `local-name()`:

  ```
  //*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='title']
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)

Comment: Yes, I tried the xpath approach that you recommended as  //*[name()='svg']/title, but it didn't work. :-(

Comment: @user12635792 I trust `name()` wasn't part of my answer but `local-name()` and moreover you haven't told us the error you are seeing. Additionally,did you check the References I have provided?

Comment: @user12635792 as recommended hierarchy in [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) try using `css_selector`

Comment: Yes @DebanjanB@user12635792, apparently, only  //*[name()='svg'] or //*[local-name()='svg'] works and not //*[local-name()='svg']/title or //*[name()='svg']/title

Comment: If Selenium has a mechanism to bind an XML namespace prefix to a namespace, it'd be preferable to use that rather than defeating the namespace via a `local-name()` predicate.  Note too that `title` is in the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace and so will require similar treatment to that given to `svg`.  (Default namespace declarations apply to the element on which they appear and all descendent elements for which no namespace is specified.)

Comment: Lovel, thanks @kjhughes, even the below worked based on your recommendations.

//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='title']

Thus we have 2 working solutions
1. //*[name()='svg']/*[name()='title']
2. svg>title

Thanks a lot

Comment: @DebanjanB: Does Selenium have a mechanism for binding XML namespace prefixes to namespaces?  I'd like to update [Defining namespaces in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40796315/290085) if it does.

Comment: @kjhughes You were right, as the `title` is within the `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace, we have to add the `name()` or `local-name()` predicate. Based on your edit, I have added the third option with `name()`.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Yes, but unfortunately AFAICT from their documentation, there is no support for binding XML namespace prefixes to namespaces in Selenium currently, so we're stuck with `name()` or `local-name()` work-arounds.  Please let me know if you know of, or come to know of, any such mechanism there.  Thank you.