# How to click on a path element within g tag using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, css-selectors

This is my full code if I will send link for you that would not work for you please run this code help me to fix it guys your 2 answers not helps for me thanks for your support

also you need to create " form_data.txt" inside you project and at this words to form_data.txt

Mark Couwell Erkek 29 07 1988 Pasport I-AG 266556

```
from ast import Return, Try
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from codecs import getencoder
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from operator import and_
from pickle import TRUE
from select import select
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By





class Project:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

    self.main()


def find_the_place_path(self):

  # firstly I will get the all path tags
  all_place_in_path = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("path")
  
  # title of my path tag is "gat: 1"
  for place in all_place_in_path:
    print(place.get_attribute('title'))
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 3":
      print(" girdim ")
      WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='coupe']//*[name()='path' and @fill-rule='nonzero']"))).click()
      time.sleep(10)
      #wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
      #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='path'][@title='gat: 3']"))).click()
      break



def find_the_place_rect(self ):

  all_place_in_rect = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("rect")

  for place in all_place_in_rect:
    print(place.get_attribute('title'))
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 1":
      self.driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//*[local-name()='svg' and @id='45']/*[localname()='path']"));
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 2":
      print("2 A girdim ")
      btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @id='45']/*[localname()='path']")
      btn.click()
      break
    if place.get_attribute('title') == "gat: 3":
       print("3 E girdim")

def input_data(self):

  data=open("form_data.txt","r")
  for line in data:
    count = 0
    data.readline()[count]
    words=line.split()
    print(words)
    if words:
      first_name = words[0]
      last_name = words[1]
      gender = words[2]
      bday = words[3]
      bmoth = words[4]
      byear = words[5]
      document_type = words[6]
      document_snumber = words[7]
      document_number = words[8]
      count += 1

    time.sleep(3)
    phone = self.driver.find_element_by_id("phone").send_keys('61260799')
    print(phone)
       
    jyns = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("jyns"))
    jyns.select_by_visible_text(gender)
 
    client_last_name = self.driver.find_element_by_id('lastname').send_keys(last_name)

    client_name = self.driver.find_element_by_id('name').send_keys(first_name)

    buyer_mail = self.driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("welbekowallanur@gmail.com")

    # WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'passport')))
    
    passport = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("passport"))
    passport.select_by_visible_text(document_type)

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'passport_code_b')))

    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.first > div.slide > div.info_r > div.wrap > ul > li > div > div.passport_code_b > div:nth-child(1)')
    pass_region = elements[0]


    passport_region = Select(pass_region.find_element_by_id("passport"))
    passport_region.select_by_visible_text(document_snumber)

    passport_code = self.driver.find_element_by_id('code').send_keys(document_number)

    day = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("bday"))
    day.select_by_visible_text(bday)

    month = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("bmonth"))
    month.select_by_visible_text(bmoth + " - Iýul")

    year = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("byear"))
    year.select_by_visible_text(byear)
    
    try:
      covid = self.driver.find_element_by_id("kepilnama").send_keys("321")
    except:
       print("Covid 19 NULL")
    
    time.sleep(3)
    choose_place_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[4]/div/button")
    choose_place_btn.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    self.find_the_place_path()

    #self.payment()


def main(self):

    self.driver.get("https://railway.gov.tm/")
    self.driver.maximize_window()

    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("one_way"))
    self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('one_way').style.display = 'block';")
    from_where =  select.select_by_visible_text("Aşgabat")
    #self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('dropdown-content').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');")
  
    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("two_way"))
    self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('two_way').style.display = 'block';")

    to_where = select.select_by_visible_text("Daşoguz")
    
    self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('search_date').setAttribute('data-value', '2022-07-29');")
    time.sleep(1)

    btn = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/a").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #change_class = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li")
    #self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'seat_1')", change_class)
    self.check_ticken()

   
def check_ticken(self):
   
   li = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
   for l in li:
      print(l.get_attribute('class'))
      if l.get_attribute("class") == "seat_1                                            ":
        print("1 - nji")
        seat = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/div/ul/li/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li").click()
        self.input_data()
        
      if l.get_attribute("class") == "seat_                                            ":
        print("2 - nji")
        self.main()
        self.driver.refresh()
                

def payment(self):

  card_number = "9931020202020202"
  card_holder = "ALLANUR WELBEKOW"
  cvc = "999"

  card_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pan_visible']").send_keys(card_number)
  d_month_select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("month"))
  d_month_selected = d_month_select.select_by_visible_text("Июль")

  d_year_select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("year"))
  d_year_selected =d_month_select.select_by_visible_text("2035")

  card_holder_fill = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='iTEXT']").send_keys(card_holder)
  cvc_fill = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='iCVC']").send_keys(cvc)
 
if __name__=="__main__":
   pr = Project()
```

Comment: Can you add an URL. Could you add the HTML as text instead of an image?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the url of the page?

Answer (score 0):

path is a svg element. use the following `xpath` to identify the element first and then click.

```
XPATH: //*[name()='path'][@title='gat: 3']
```

To click on dynamic element use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='path'][@title='gat: 3']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: sory that not helps for me

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<path>` element as it is within [**SVG**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63544849/7429447) namespace you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg g.coupe path[fill-rule='nonzero']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='coupe']//*[name()='path' and @fill-rule='nonzero']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: sory that not helps for me