# How to extract data inside svg viewbox using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using this URL https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g32655-d7222445-Reviews-The_Anchor-Los_Angeles_California.html, where there is a `svg` view box when I try to click it shows working hours. I need to extract those using python selenium. Could anyone please help? I am new to web scraping.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The data about opening hours is stored inside the HTML page in Json form, so to get the opening hours, you can use this example:

```py
import re
import json
import requests


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"
}

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g32655-d7222445-Reviews-The_Anchor-Los_Angeles_California.html"

html_text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

data = re.search(r"window\.__WEB_CONTEXT__=(\{.*\});\(", html_text).group(1)
data = data.replace("pageManifest", '"pageManifest"')
data = json.loads(data)
data = data["pageManifest"]["redux"]["api"]["responses"]

for k, v in data.items():
    if "/hours" in k:
        print(v)
        break
```

Prints:

```
{
    "data": {
        "openStatus": "CLOSED",
        "openStatusText": "Closed Now",
        "hoursTodayText": "Hours Today: 4:00 pm - 11:59 pm",
        "currentHoursText": "",
        "allOpenHours": [
            {"days": "Tue - Fri", "times": ["4:00 pm - 11:59 pm"]},
            {"days": "Sat - Sun", "times": ["11:00 am - 11:59 pm"]},
        ],
        "addHoursLink": {
            "url": "/UpdateListing-d7222445#Hours-only",
            "text": "+ Add hours",
        },
    },
    "error": None,
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine and changes it to work in a selenium driver @Andrej Kesely

Answer (score 0):

To click on the [*SVG*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544775/reading-title-tag-in-svg/63544849#63544849) element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurant_Review-g32655-d7222445-Reviews-The_Anchor-Los_Angeles_California.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-automation='top-info-hours'] > div svg[width='18px'] path:nth-child(2)"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Hours']//following::div[1]"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Sun
  11:00 AM - 11:59 PM
  Tue
  4:00 PM - 11:59 PM
  Wed
  4:00 PM - 11:59 PM
  Thu
  4:00 PM - 11:59 PM
  Fri
  4:00 PM - 11:59 PM
  Sat
  11:00 AM - 11:59 PM
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```