# How to use find_element_by_xpath() for svg element using Selenium for Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to make an Instagram bot to like a post if it's unliked, and to ignore it if it's already liked
I've managed to grab the div element and click it, but for the like detection code I need the attribute for `"aria-label"` or `"fill"` for the bot to specify if the post is liked or not, but I haven't managed to grab the `svg` element to do so.

Here's the like button structure

[image: 1]

and here's my code:

```
like_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
'//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div')
          
like_icon=like_button.find_element_by_xpath(
'//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span/svg')
```

Whenever i run it an error occurs:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button/div/span/svg"}
```

Comment: svg[aria-label='Like'] would be an easier xpath to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is a dynamic [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139), so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  like_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button span > svg[aria-label='Like']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  like_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button//span//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Reading title tag in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544775/reading-title-tag-in-svg/63544849#63544849)
- [How to click on SVG elements using XPath and Selenium WebDriver through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)
- [Unable to locate SVG elements through xpath on Kendo UI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236662/unable-to-locate-svg-elements-through-xpath-on-kendo-ui-chart/54237441#54237441)
- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)