# How can define/locate this xpath <g> using this ID?

Tags: xpath

[I'm kinda having a challenge locating this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm4r5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this: `//g[@id="box_0"]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Already tried it but didn't really work. I somehow solved it but I'm not pretty sure if this is the good way to do it. I mean, it's a good practice etc.

I did it this way: //*[contains(@id, 'box_0')]");

I'm new to automation so I still have to learn things.

Answer (score 0):

To grab SVG elements using XPath

Please go through : [How to use xPath in Selenium WebDriver to grab SVG elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520642/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements)

In Your case any of the below should work:

```
//*[contains(@id,'box_0')]

//*[name()='g' and contains(@id,'box_0')]
```