# Find element contains specific "path" attribute

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors, cypress

Can someone please assist with the following issue?

I have map with more than 2000 elements loaded, but only one of them (which is currently visible) has the element '**path**' with an attribute **d** different than zero. For easier understanding, refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

Tried with this: [SVG & Path finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520642/how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium-webdriver-to-grab-svg-elements), but did not find what I was looking for.

And having this XPath:

```
//div[@id="map"]//div[contains(@class,"map")]//div[@class="leaflet-pane"]//div[@class="leaflet-pane2"]//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and @d="M0 0"]
```

which finds all of them (2000).

What I am looking for is something like this (though I could not find the correct solution) - deliberately just added end of Xpath.

In summary, I need the **d** attribute (inside path) to not contain the value zero:

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and @d(contains,"125")]
```

Please assist, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your descriptions you are looking for locator where **d** attribute value is **not** equals to `M0 0`.
This can be translated to XPath with `not` operator.
Please try this:

```
//div[@id="map"]//div[contains(@class,"map")]//div[@class="leaflet-pane"]//div[@class="leaflet-pane2"]//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='path' and(not(@d="M0 0"))]
```